# No network access from MacOS terminal

Tags: networking, mac, terminal

A colleague's Macbook refuses to make any remote connections from the terminal. For example:

```
macbook-pro% rvm install "ruby-3.2.2"                                                                             /.../API/FAIRsharing-API 13:18
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/13.4/x86_64/ruby-3.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Warning: formula.jws.json: update failed, falling back to cached version.
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: formulae.brew.sh   #          #          #

Warning: cask.jws.json: update failed, falling back to cached version.
==> Upgrading 2 outdated packages:
coreutils 9.1 -> 9.3
openssl@1.1 1.1.1s -> 1.1.1t
==> Fetching openssl@1.1
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1t
Error: openssl@1.1: Failed to download resource "openssl@1.1_bottle_manifest"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.22\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 13.4\)\ curl/7.88.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --header Accept:\ application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1\+json --header Authorization:\ Bearer\ QQ== --fail --location --silent --head https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1t` exited with 6. Here's the output:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ghcr.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ghcr.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ghcr.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ghcr.io


==> Fetching coreutils
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/coreutils/manifests/9.3
Error: coreutils: Failed to download resource "coreutils_bottle_manifest"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.22\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 13.4\)\ curl/7.88.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --header Accept:\ application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1\+json --header Authorization:\ Bearer\ QQ== --fail --location --silent --head https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/coreutils/manifests/9.3` exited with 35. Here's the output:
curl: (35) Recv failure: Socket is not connected


Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

He doesn't have any network proxy enabled. This problem is currently manifesting on a standard domestic broadband connection. There is no VPN active and turning on a Cisco VPN makes no difference.

There's no problem using web browsers on this Mac; they are able to connect.

Of course, it's been rebooted, and the following instructions from the local IT department have been followed:

> If you are experiencing connection issues on a Mac, it might be the
> computer's network stack is broken and needs to be recreated. This can
> affect both wired and wireless networks at the same time. The
> instructions we use are included below for reference, but if you would
> prefer IT can do this with you.
>
> Go to this location in Finder/Terminal (make sure it is the system
> Library and not the user profile Library)
> /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ Delete any of the files in
> that folder called the below, or with similar names such as .backup or
> pre-upgrade. com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
> com.apple.network.identification.plist
> com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist NetworkInterfaces.plist
> preferences.plist Restart the computer Try connecting to a network
> again. If this fails, try the following:
>
> Delete any networking profiles under System Preferences -> Profiles.
> Delete the remembered network you are trying to connect to. Check in
> Network Preferences if any additional options have a green light that
> would not be expected (e.g. Cisco VPN is green and saying connected
> when you are not connected to any network), and uninstall the
> applications that have these options (not just remove them from the
> Network Preferences).

A third-party terminal application also showed the same problems.
Can anyone suggest where to look next?

Comment: This is more on topic on SuperUser or https://apple.stackexchange.com/ - Note that `Could not resolve host:` points at first glance to a DNS issue (which may not be show in a web browser that uses application specific DNS settings rather than the system defaults that a console app would be using) check `scutil --dns` and/or on OSX legacy `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Ah, yes. As I usually use system defaults in browsers it didn't occur to me that he might have set his to use something else.